# Save the contents of a message I sent through webform

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-mate

Sometimes I want to save the contents of a message I sent to a company or website using a webform. (As a reminder of what I sent.)

I use Firefox.

Is there a way other than doing a Print Screen?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click in the body of your message, do <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the text, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the text, then open your favorite text editor and do <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to paste and save. Since it's a new file, you will be prompted for the file path and name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a firefox plugin called clippings that puts its icon on the location bar with others. copy your message, open that and paste into it.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/clippings/?src=search

Comment: You *can* use Clippings for this purpose, but TBH the its role is quite the opposite. Clippings lets you store canned texts to paste  later which are frequently-entered in webpages (instead of retyping or repetitive copying-and-pasting all the time).